# Handle exceptional condition when file name already exists and also if directory path fetched is invalid

Tags: java, exception, servlets, io

I would like to handle exceptions when directory is not present and also when the file is already created with the same prefix in the Servlet.

If my servlet after getting a request writes a PDF to `FileOutputStream` and sends redirect to previous receipt page successfully I don't want a message explaining cause written to request scope.

But when the directory does not exist (directory variable brings in path like `'D:\pdf'`) or if similar named file exist I want to send a sample error message in request scope.

So is my conditional expression correct? Am I using `FileOutputStream` and also `ServletOutputStream` the way it is meant to be? I have read that one servlet can either send to `ServletOutputStream` or write to `PrintWriter`.

I would be much obliged for any guidance or for sending me in the right direction.

Here is the overridden method of the servlet,

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("headr " + request.getHeader("referer"));
        // response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        // response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=pdf.pdf");
        // response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);  

        String prefix = request.getParameter("prefix");
        String no = request.getParameter("no");
        String html = request.getParameter("source");

        String directory = new SibsDelegate().getDirectoryPath();

        File file = new File(directory);
        if ( file.exists() && !new File(file, "prefix"+"-"+"no").exists())
        {
            System.out.println("exists");
           try 
           {
              HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
              CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();

              TagNode node = cleaner.clean(html);

              // OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

              final XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new PrettyXmlSerializer(props);
              final String html1 = xmlSerializer.getAsString(node);

              ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
              renderer.setDocumentFromString(html1);
              renderer.layout();

              String filename = prefix + "-" + no +".pdf";
              String fileNameWithPath = "D:\\pdf\\" + filename;
              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( fileNameWithPath, false);
              renderer.createPDF( fos );
              fos.close();

              System.out.println( "PDF: '" + fileNameWithPath + "' created." );

              RequestDispatcher rd = null;
              // set message in request scope -- TODO
              request.getRequestDispatcher("Common_Receipt.jsp").forward(request, response);


              //  response.sendRedirect("Common_Receipt.jsp");


            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                // fos.close();
            }

        }  

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file checking looks good but I won't break it up to 2 differents errors types handled differently instead I would put the directory checking outside the try catch and the file checking inside so you can handle the error with your `IOExceptions`:

```
if (!file.exists() || !file.isDirectory()) {
    // handle directory doesnt exist
    // note that "error" is just a string variable you can make it whatever you want
    request.setAttribute("error", "Directory already exists!!!!!");
    // you can output this attribue in your jsp to tell the user there was an error
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Common_Receipt.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    File outputFile = new File(file, "prefix"+"-"+"no");
    if(outputFile.exists()) {
        // handle file output already exists
        throw new FileAlreadyExistsException(prefix+"-"+no+".pdf");
    }
    fos = new FileOutputStream( outputFile, false);

    // do your writing to the file here
} catch(FileAlreadyExistsException e) {
    request.setAttribute("error", "your file already exists dummy");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Common_Receipt.jsp").forward(request, response);
} catch(IOException e) {
    // had a problem writing to the file, you decide how to handle it, or group it with the FileAlreadyExistsException. Note that FileAlreadyExistsException extends IOException so to group then just put
    // your code from the FileAlreadyExistsException block into here
    request.setAttribute("error", "woah something bad happened");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Common_Receipt.jsp").forward(request, response);
} finnaly {
    if(fos != null) fos.close();
}
```

Let me know if that answered your question, I was a little confused reading through your question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time answering my question. Your approach looks promising to me. Would you care to explain your strategy where you keep the `check-if-directory-exists` code outide the `try-catch` block?

Comment: I try to not put code inside try catches that I dont want handled by the exception. In this case if something were to go wrong with the directory exists code (like an IOException) I dont want it being handled in the try catch I want it to throw an error back to me so I can see what went wrong and fix the problem so it doesnt happen again.